# onload variable initialization

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button which increments a variable value, and I use this variable to load specific content. My problem is that after the page has loaded, I have to click 3 times for the first content load:

1st time I click: I get an undefined result because no ID is loaded
2nd time: the input field value from before I reload the page disappears
3rd time: the first content finally loads

Once the first content has loaded everything works fine. From what I understood it is because the variable isn't initalized at page loading. So I added an onload event but it doesn't work at all.

the script :

```js
var Pokemon_ID = 1

function changePokemon(Pokemon_ID) {

  function resetID() {
    document.getElementById("id-input").innerHTML = Pokemon_ID;
  }

  document.getElementById("right-btn").onclick = function() {
    Pokemon_ID++;
    document.getElementById("id-input").value = Pokemon_ID;
    document.getElementById("id-input").click();
  }

  document.getElementById("left-btn").onclick = function() {
    if (Pokemon_ID > 1) {
      Pokemon_ID--;
    }
    document.getElementById("id-input").value = Pokemon_ID;
    document.getElementById("id-input").click();
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { //IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

      var parts = xmlhttp.responseText.split('|')
      document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = parts[0];
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = parts[1];
      document.getElementById("type-display1").innerHTML = parts[2];
      document.getElementById("categorie").innerHTML = "Categorie: " + parts[3];
      document.getElementById("talent").innerHTML = "Talent: " + parts[4];
      document.getElementById("taille").innerHTML = "Taille: " + parts[5];
      document.getElementById("poids").innerHTML = "Poids: " + parts[6];

    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_id.php?q=" + Pokemon_ID, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="pokedex" onload="resetID()">

  <a id="right-btn" onclick="changePokemon(this.value)"></a>

  <a id="left-btn" onclick="changePokemon(this.value)"></a>

  <form>
    <input type="number" id="id-input" onclick="changePokemon(this.value)">
  </form>

</div>
```

I also tried to declare my variable inside the changePokemon() function, but only the first id was loading I couldn't change the value of Pokemon_ID.
I tried to use const and let but both of them also didn't work

Comment: Anchor elements don't have a value, what is `this.value` supposed tomean in `right-btn` and `left-btn`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same name `Pokemon_ID` for the global variable and the parameter to the `changePokemon()` function. The parameter is a local variable, so assignments to it don't affect the global variable. Give it a different name.

You need to take `resetID()` out of the `changePokemon()` function. It needs tobe in the global scope so it can be accessed from `onclick`.

To change an input, you need to assign to `.value`, not `.innerHTML`.

DIVs don't have a `load` event. You need to put `onload="resetID()"` in the `<body>` tag, or write:

```
window.onload = resetID;
```

in the Javascript.

```js
var Pokemon_ID = 1

function resetID() {
  document.getElementById("id-input").value = Pokemon_ID;
}

function changePokemon(Pokemon_val) {


  document.getElementById("right-btn").onclick = function() {
    Pokemon_ID++;
    document.getElementById("id-input").value = Pokemon_ID;
    document.getElementById("id-input").click();
  }

  document.getElementById("left-btn").onclick = function() {
    if (Pokemon_ID > 1) {
      Pokemon_ID--;
    }
    document.getElementById("id-input").value = Pokemon_ID;
    document.getElementById("id-input").click();
  }

  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { //IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

      var parts = xmlhttp.responseText.split('|')
      document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = parts[0];
      document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = parts[1];
      document.getElementById("type-display1").innerHTML = parts[2];
      document.getElementById("categorie").innerHTML = "Categorie: " + parts[3];
      document.getElementById("talent").innerHTML = "Talent: " + parts[4];
      document.getElementById("taille").innerHTML = "Taille: " + parts[5];
      document.getElementById("poids").innerHTML = "Poids: " + parts[6];

    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "get_id.php?q=" + Pokemon_val, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="pokedex" onload="resetID()">

  <a id="right-btn" onclick="changePokemon(this.value)"></a>

  <a id="left-btn" onclick="changePokemon(this.value)"></a>

  <form>
    <input type="number" id="id-input" onclick="changePokemon(this.value)">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, it fixed it but my onload event doesn't make the content load on my page. I would like to empty the "id-input" field onload or make the content appear directly when the page loads. Can you help me please ?

Comment: `onXXX` attributes are executed in the global scope, so you need to move `resetID()` out of the function.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but the value in "id-input" still doesn't reset on reload even if I moved it out of the function

Comment: I just checked on Chrome, it works but the ID 1 doesn't show until I increment to ID 2. And on firefox it doesn't work at all

Comment: `resetID()` was assigning to `.innerHTML`, not `.value`.

Comment: You can't use `onload` on a DIV, it has to be in the `<body>` element.

Comment: it still doesn't fix it sorry

Comment: Is the function being called?

Comment: thank you! it's fixed now but there is just a little problem, the value doesn't appear for the first ID until I increment to ID 2 and I go back to ID 1 (when I set the onload value to: " " to empty it, because when I set it to 1 nothing appears at page loading). Any idea why ?

Comment: Thanks! Everything is fixed now. Instead of putting a resetID() function, I removed it and I putted this single line at the beginning of changePokemon() : document.getElementById("id-input").value=Pokemon_ID;  Now everything works fine